# marker should point to location and if user drags the marker the location should be in textbox

Tags: html, asp.net, google-maps

I am new to google maps. I have gone through many posts but didnt find what I wanted. I want to achieve this: [improve-my-city](http://www.improve-my-city.com/livedemo/report/)

But I am only able to get user location and drag marker. I want the marker to move to the position entered on the map on button click vice versa when a user drags the marker the address should be in the textbox. Also my infowindow does not show.

As I am working with Asp.net my html page is different and my map shows in iframe on aspx page. Textbox and button is in .aspx page

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

    function initMap() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,  showError);
        } else {
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }

        function showError(error) {
            switch (error.code) {
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                    x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
                    break;
                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                    x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
                    break;
                case error.TIMEOUT:
                    x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed  out."
                    break;
                case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                    x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
                    break;
            }
        }
        updateMarkerPosition(latlon);
         geocodePosition(latlon);
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        lon = position.coords.longitude;
        latlon = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
        mapholder = document.getElementById('map')

        var myOptions = {
            center: latlon,
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            navigationControlOptions:
            { style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL }
        }

        var contentString = 'Drag red marker <br/> to improve geo-location';
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlon,
            map: map,
            title: 'Report refers to this location',
            draggable: true
        });



        // Add dragging event listeners.
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function () {
            updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function () {
            updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
            updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {
            updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
            geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
        });


    }


</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"
        async defer>
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Ashwini ..At what point did you get .. what is the first goal you want to reach?

Comment: Hi scais. I want the location where the marker is pointing should be passed into textbox

Comment: I'm playing with your code but when I try to drag the marke the console give an error .. updateMarkerStatus is not defined...eplain me .. is this you want to implement?

Comment: This Evening a can  help  you  time by time .. you must be patient

Comment: I also get the same error. I dont know what to do with it. Take your time I will wait. :)

Comment: Ok let's do a bit of order .. you're referring to these functions but not use them. (updateMarkerPosition (LatLon); geocodePosition (LatLon); updateMarkerAddress ('Dragging ...'); updateMarkerStatus ('Dragging ...');) is there any reason why there are these functions or are just a first draft of the functions that we will define as will serve us ..?

Comment: Actually I got this code from one or more threads and then I edited it as per my requirements. So I also dont know what exactly those things are for.. I tried defining updatemarkerPosition but my map was not visible, then I removed  (updateMarkerPosition (LatLon); geocodePosition (LatLon); but the marker started floating

Comment: First I' trying to prepare a code without the first error when is ready I post in answer so we can eval astarting functioning code.. after we go to you goal...

Comment: okay. I am also trying from my side..

Comment: I have posted a first answer whit functioning code without missing function error and a simple div for echo the main action.. comment me when you have the same code functioning ... (when you drag .. in the top left you some brief message)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sample show the address of the position of the marker when drag end.

This should be enough to understand how the reverse geocoding work (get the address from the coordinates of a point)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var geocoder;

    function initMap() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,  showError);
        } else {
            x=document.getElementById("msg");
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }

        function showError(error) {
            x=document.getElementById("msg");
            switch (error.code) {
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                    x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
                    break;
                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                    x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
                    break;
                case error.TIMEOUT:
                    x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed  out."
                    break;
                case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                    x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
                    break;
            }
        }



        //updateMarkerPosition(latlon);
        //geocodePosition(latlon);
    }

     function geocodePosition(pos) {
        x=document.getElementById("msg");
        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': pos}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
               x.innerHTML = results[0].formatted_address;
              }
          } else {
            x.innerHTML = "Geocoder non possibile";
          }  
        });

    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        lon = position.coords.longitude;
        latlon = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
        mapholder = document.getElementById('map')

        var myOptions = {
            center: latlon,
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            navigationControlOptions:
            { style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL }
        }

        var contentString = 'Drag red marker <br/> to improve geo-location';
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlon,
            map: map,
            title: 'Report refers to this location',
            draggable: true
        });


        // Add dragging event listeners.
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function (evt) {
             x=document.getElementById("msg");
             x.innerHTML = '<p>Dragging ... Marker dropped: Current Lat: ' + evt.latLng.lat() + ' Current Lng: ' + evt.latLng.lng() + '</p>';
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function (evt) {
             x=document.getElementById("msg");
             x.innerHTML = '<p>Dragging ... again .... Marker position: Current Lat: ' + evt.latLng.lat() + ' Current Lng: ' + evt.latLng.lng() + '</p>';
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (evt) {
            x=document.getElementById("msg");
            x.innerHTML =  '<p>Drag .. ended ... Marker dropped: Current Lat: ' + evt.latLng.lat() + ' Current Lng: ' + evt.latLng.lng() + '</p>';
            geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
        });

    }


  </script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"
        async defer>
  </script>
```

Comment: The marker floats when clicked.  and the console shows an error updateMarkerAddress not defined when I directly run the html page. But it is working on another page ie., aspx ...

Comment: You must copy the code i provided.. where the functions not useful are commented and where is added a div with id='msg' ... and in the listener are added properly messages..

Comment: then now when you move the marker you see the brief message on top left div and no error in console.. Next step we try to get coordinate from the point where drag end  and show in div ... I provide the code later..

Comment: I have update the answer ...now the code show the coordinates of the markers... dinamically..

Comment: Well a first question I think is solved or you have the element for adapting to your code.. As I say a question by time..if you have problem or you want understand better .comment me.. otherwise . rate as accepted and rate also as useful .. in a next questions we can see how continue with your goals

Comment: heya... It works very well. I can see the co-ordinates as well as the address.

Comment: @Ashwini  if my answer is useful please rate it as useful too .. voting up te left up arrow near the asnwer title..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34677123/google-map-marker-to-show-location-in-textbox-rather-than-div-tag