# Google map marker to show location in textbox rather than div tag

Tags: html, asp.net, google-maps

Currently when the map marker is dragged the position is shown in the div tag but I want to show it in the textbox not in the div.  **I want it int textbox txtLoc.** It shows currently in div ie., 'msg'. Also my infowindow is not showing.

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLoc" CssClass="form-control" 
     runat="server"   style="margin-left:120px" ></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
    <button ID="lblFind" runat="server" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">
     Find   location on map</button>
    <br/><br />
     <div id='msg'></div>
     <div id="map" style="height:300px;width:600px"></div>
      </div>



    var geocoder;
    function initMap() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,  showError);
    } else {
    x=document.getElementById("msg");
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}

    function showError(error) {
    x=document.getElementById("msg");
    switch (error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed  out."
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
            break;
    }
   }

  }

     function geocodePosition(pos) {
     x=document.getElementById("msg");
     geocoder.geocode({'latLng': pos}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[0]) {
            x.innerHTML = results[0].formatted_address;

        }
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geocoder non possibile";
    }  
  });

  }

  function showPosition(position) {
  lat = position.coords.latitude;
  lon = position.coords.longitude;
  latlon = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
  mapholder = document.getElementById('map')

    var myOptions = {
    center: latlon,
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    navigationControlOptions:
    { style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL }
  }

   var contentString = 'Drag red marker <br/> to improve geo-location';
   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });
   infowindow.open(map, marker);

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlon,
    map: map,
    title: 'Report refers to this location',
    draggable: true
});


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function (evt) {
    x=document.getElementById("msg"); 
   });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function (evt) {
    x=document.getElementById("msg");
   });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (evt) {
    x=document.getElementById("msg");
   geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
  });

}
```

Comment: Hi @Aswhini .. i posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working version of the code with text box (also) for show the reverse geocode result
look at the new version of geocodePosition (the function addAddress() It is no longer necessary)

```
<body >
 <!--  div id="map" style="width: 1800px; height: 1300px"></div-->
<input id="txtLoc" type="text" name="testname"  style="width: 400px;"><br>
<div id='msg'>Test</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">



    var geocoder;

    function initMap() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,  showError);
        } else {
            x=document.getElementById("msg");
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }

        function showError(error) {
            x=document.getElementById("msg");
            switch (error.code) {
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                    x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
                    break;
                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                    x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
                    break;
                case error.TIMEOUT:
                    x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed  out."
                    break;
                case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                    x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
                    break;
            }
        }



        //updateMarkerPosition(latlon);
        //geocodePosition(latlon);
    }

     function geocodePosition(pos) {
        x=document.getElementById("msg");
        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': pos}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
               x.innerHTML = results[0].formatted_address;
               y  = document.getElementById("txtLoc");
               y.value =  results[0].formatted_address;


              }
          } else {
            x.innerHTML = "Geocoder non possibile";
          }  
        });

    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        lon = position.coords.longitude;
        latlon = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
        mapholder = document.getElementById('map')

        var myOptions = {
            center: latlon,
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            navigationControlOptions:
            { style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL }
        }

        var contentString = 'Drag red marker <br/> to improve geo-location';
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlon,
            map: map,
            title: 'Report refers to this location',
            draggable: true
        });


        // Add dragging event listeners.
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function (evt) {
             x=document.getElementById("msg");
             x.innerHTML = '<p>Dragging ... Marker dropped: Current Lat: ' + evt.latLng.lat() + ' Current Lng: ' + evt.latLng.lng() + '</p>';
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function (evt) {
             x=document.getElementById("msg");
             x.innerHTML = '<p>Dragging ... again .... Marker position: Current Lat: ' + evt.latLng.lat() + ' Current Lng: ' + evt.latLng.lng() + '</p>';
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (evt) {
            x=document.getElementById("msg");
            x.innerHTML =  '<p>Drag .. ended ... Marker dropped: Current Lat: ' + evt.latLng.lat() + ' Current Lng: ' + evt.latLng.lng() + '</p>';
            geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
        });

    }


  </script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"
        async defer>
  </script>

  </body>
```

Comment: I got this error again Cannot set property 'value' of null. and div showing the location not textbox

Comment: This mean javscript document.getElementById("txtLoc"); can't get the id from the textBox. Check for eventally mistake..Be sure the TextBox is visuble,,  and for test try change the <asp:TextBox.. > with a normal <input ..> like i did.

Comment: Can you tell me some other way. I mean let the text be in div I will make it hidden and pass the div content to textbox.  Bcoz I have that asp textbox control passing value to database.

Comment: I imagined ..well. first we can try to find the correct id name  is renderer in the html page.. for this try to eval the html code generated for the page (with firefox you can press CTRL + u and show the a page with source code.. search for a an input related to your filed and get the right id value ... then use this in getElementById(..)

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: I took the textbox element id from the console and replaced it with 'msg' in the code. Now the address is displayed in textbox.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37103845/how-to-get-current-location-in-textbox-using-geolocation